# add javascript files to wordpress footer according to page width

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to add js files to WordPress footer id page width is larger than

```
<?php if(is_home()){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var wid = $(window).width();
if(wid>970){
<?=
'<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/slider.js"></script>'
?>  
}
});
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

I've tried using .append() but sure I'm facing the same problem and it doesn't add the files because the script code contains double quotes and single quotes while it's wrapped in a single quote

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the code to inject  tag into the HTML, do it by this:

```
<?php if(is_home()){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var wid = $(window).width(),
        scriptName = wid > 970 ? 'script.js' : 'slider.js',
        url = "<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/" + scriptName,
        script = document.createElement( 'script' );
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    $("body").append( script );
});
</script>
```

It checks page's width, according to that, select the script's name then inject is to the end of the body.

Comment: could you print or show an screenshot of the generated JS? also what console errors do you have?

Comment: console: Use of attributes' nodeValue attribute is deprecated. Use value instead. 
The Web Console logging API (console.log, console.info, console.warn, console.error) has been disabled by a script on this page.
used $("div#footer").append() but the footer totally disappeared

Comment: those are Firefox's warnings, can i see generated code? you can also do a document.write instead creating script element.

Comment: footer code didn't change at all and it doesn't contain any of the scripts and the slideshow didn't work and here's the embed code: http://s8.postimg.org/q3j0usqs5/Untitled_1.gif

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to include the js file in js like this :

```
function includeJS() {
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/slider.js"></script>'); 
  }

var wid = $(window).width();
 if(wid>970) {
    includeJS();
  }
```

Comment: didn't work and I got this in the page  
'); } var wid = $(window).width(); if(wid>970) { includeJS(); } });

Comment: have you placed the the above inside  the   <?php if(is_home()){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript"> ....... </script>   ?